# Nikon Wireless Remote Controller WR-R10/WR-T10 backwards compatibility

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, nikon-d90, remote, wireless-triggers

Ever since the press release, everywhere I look for details on [Nikon’s **WR-R10** wireless transceiver and **WR-T10** wireless transmitter](http://www.nikon.com/news/2012/1106_dslr_01.htm), I always seem to find them mentioned in conjunction with the new Nikon D5200.

> Remote control is more convenient with the D5200 due to support for the WR-R10 (transceiver) and WR-T10 (transmitter) that utilize electromagnetic waves.

I read that the WR-R10 and WR-T10 are [compatible with *specific* Nikon D-SLRs](http://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/product/accessories/slr/slr-connectivity/remote-control/wireless-remote-controller/transceiver-wr-r10).
Are they compatible with other older cameras, say **D90** or **D7000**?

---

**Update:** I see there's also a [WR-A10 adapter](http://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/product/accessories/slr/slr-connectivity/remote-control/adapter-wr-a10):

> Adapter to convert the ten-pin remote terminal of the camera to the **new accessory terminal** for the WR-R10 Wireless Remote Controller.

Anyone knows how different is this *new* accessory terminal from the current one, like on a D90/D7000?

[image: Accessory Terminal]

Comment: Have you tried calling or emailing Nikon? If so, and you got an answer, add it here and mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Did you find out about this? Any adapters for D7000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nikon US page says the WR-R10/T10 are compatible with both cameras:
http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Remote-Transmitters/WR-R10-Wireless-Remote-Controller-%28transceiver%29.html

You need both devices, since the T10 transmits and the R10 receives. (The UK page isn't clear about it, but shows the same lineup of cameras in the "Related products" tab.)

The WR-A10 is used on other cameras to adapt the R10 module to the camera body. You won't need this for the D90 or D7000.